# Android Google Drive REST API offline cache

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-android-api

In my app I have implemented the Google Drive Android API, which as of December 8 2018 has been deprecated, and requests will fail in December 2019. They recommend migrating to the REST API.

In their [explanation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation) they mention that:

> There are virtually no functional differences between Android and REST API calls, and for most clients the required code changes will be syntactic only.

But one of the main benefits my app is based around is the android APIs ability to seamlessly handle offline queries. (ie: When the device is offline and the user requests drive files, it uses an offline local cache, which can be read from and written to. When the tablet connects to wifi the local cache is synced with google drive, all handled by the android OS, while the app isn't even running.) From the Google Drive Android API docs:

> The Drive Android API lets your app access files even if the device is offline. To support offline cases, the API implements a sync engine that runs in the background to merge upstream and downstream changes as network access is available and to resolve conflicts.

Is this functionality possible with the Google Drive REST API for android?

Comment: You might want to check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/sync-google-drive-files-to-apps-using-the-drive-rest-api-bidding-farewell-to-the-drive-android-api) that stated you can continue to provide an offline-first model by using a [`SyncAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/) with the Drive REST API.

Comment: I'm very interested too. My apps send backup files to Google Drive even when the device is offline.